# Assign values to a specific row and multiple columns in a dataframe based on a condition

Tags: r

I am stuck writing some code and I need your help. The problem is as follows:

I have a data frame called "table" which looks like this:

```
> dput(table)
structure(list(ID = c(1405720, 1700870, 1774430, 1844160, 2187710, 
2215320, 2513640, 2581470, 2880020, 3092980, 5514080, 5519800, 
5537980, 5553200, 5556930, 5562970, 5565930, 5605290, 5632260, 
5632260), LA = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1), tA = c(450, 480, 590, 400, 335, 430, 480, 1035, 
570, 590, 480, 484, 528, 460, 380, 520, 420, 420, 515, 515), 
    tB = c(1080, 810, 930, 960, 960, 960, 810, 1035, 765, 1080, 
    990, 1140, 528, 750, 660, 855, 975, 975, 990, 990)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

In this data fram  "ID" represents a person and "tA" and "tB" represent two times of the day measured in minutes and starting at 00:00 am.

I do also have another data frame called "df_time" which contains the "IDs" and a column for every minute of the day filled with zeros.

```
df_time <- matrix(0,nrow = 20 , ncol = 1441, byrow=TRUE)
df_time[,1] <- table$ID
```

I do now want to alter the zero values in df_time based on a condition. The condition is as follows:
If table$LA == 1 fill the columns in df_time from table$tA to table$tB with 1s.
Else leave the 0s in df_time.
Here is a little example:
Let's say in the first row of "table" LA == 1 and tA == 450 and tB == 600.
The code should now fill all the columns in the first row of df_time with the column-numbers from 451 to 601 with 1s. 
(I needed to add +1 to the time "tA" and "tB" because of the "ID"-column taking the first place/column in my data frame df_time and thus the minutes of the day start at the second column.)

The following code is one of the code snippets I have tried to use.
Hopefully this code also helps you to understand the condition.
I needed to add +1 to the time "tA" and "tB" because of the "ID"-column taking the first place/column in my data frame df_time and thus the minutes of the day start at the second column.
z is just a random assignment I chose for the else statement. It doesn't do anything.

```
for(i in nrow(table)){
  if (table[i,"LA"] == 1){
    x = table[i, "tA"]+1
    y = table[i, "tB"]+1
  } else {
    z = 0
  }

  df_time[i, x:y] <- 1

}
```

Comment: `for (i in nrow(table))` just loops over one element. Try `1:nrow(table)` instead.

Comment: ...and perhaps you could replace `z=0` with `next()`

Comment: @MartinGal Thank you very much. Sadly I did not notice this little mistake by myself.

Comment: So where `LA` is 0 you want to keep 0's as it is?

Comment: For the simplicity of my question and the data I presented, yes, if LA == 0 I don't want to alter the specific row in df_time. My actual data is little more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way without a loop :

```
#Initialize the `df_time` dataframe
df_time <- matrix(0,nrow = 20 , ncol = 1440)
#Get row index where LA = 1
inds <- which(table$LA == 1)
#Create a sequence between tA and tB columns adding creating row column matrix
#and turn those values to 1
df_time[do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y, z) cbind(z, x:y), 
                table$tA[inds], table$tB[inds], inds))] <- 1
```

I did not add `ID` value initially to avoid doing `+1` to `tA` and `tB` columns. You can `cbind` it to the result.

```
cbind(table$ID, df_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `data.table` will provide an efficient and fairly clear solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(table)
table[LA==1,tA:=tA+1]
table[LA==1,tB:=tB+1]
```